# re-run failed python import script in crontab untill succeed

Tags: python, import, cron, restart

I have following line in my crontab:

```
# Import data from DB 
0 3 * * * bash -ic "python /home/python/td.py"
```

This script run query on one dataset and import results to another. Because of huge amount of data sometimes it fail.

I am looking for the simplest method to re-run this script until it succeeds. Maybe i should check any log file or make it first and then check? Maybe check destination database if data for this day are already there? Can i do this directly in cron or should write another script for checking?

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: That kind of logic should probably be in your script, i.e. it should check if the data is available before doing anything with it.

Comment: But data are always available on source but sometimes i must run 2-3 times import script to import them. How to automate this process?

Comment: If you don't want to implement retry on error in your script, you could wrap it in a shell script that retries it. But I'd rather advise you to handle errors cleanly and retry in the script itself.

Answer (score 0):

I created another script (`dbcheck.py`) which checks if data are in destination db (simple count(*)). I will schedule it in crontab after import script.

```
# Import data from DB 
0 3 * * * bash -ic "python /home/python/import.py"
# Check data in DB 
0 4 * * * bash -ic "python /home/python/dbcheck.py"
```

How to run again `import.py` if select count(*) in `dbcheck.py` will return 0?